# south django migrate

Tags: django, django-south

I installed south and I try to use it to migrate now:

./manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial

I get a :

-bash: ./manage.py: Permission denied

and if I sudo I get:

sudo: ./manage.py: command not found

Response.

Whats wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `manage.py` isn't executable. Simply pass it to the interpreter instead.

```
python manage.py ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make it executable:

`sudo chmod u+x`

So you can run it like `./manage.py`